# jump to vim commands help from vim script or vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim, keystroke

when i'm modifying a .vim file or the .vimrc i can get vim helps by running a simple command like this

```
:help modelines
```

and shows me the help in a split window.

but how can i get the same help, with a keystroke combo in stead of typing the command? like jumping with tags "C-]" but for a command in source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:set keywordprg=:help
```

Then type <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>